# .Net C# Request variables for showing blog post not working. Error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

I'm trying to create a simple blog where I can post and for it to save to a db and display each blog post using Request Variables, however I get the following error:

> The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

**This is my DisplayBlog.aspx.cs CodeFile** :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class DisplayBlog : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.PopulateBlog();
    }
}


private void PopulateBlog()
{
    string blogId = Request["blogid"];
    string query = "SELECT [Title], [Body] FROM [Blogs] WHERE [BlogId] = @BlogId";
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogId", blogId);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    lblTitle.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
                    lblBody.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Body"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Request` is a property of the `Page` class - are you certain the method is within the `Page` class? I suspect it's a copy-paste since your code has "fancy" quotes (`“blogid”`)

Comment: `Request("blogid")` - Where do you define a *method* called `Request`?

Comment: Sorry, no "fancy" quotes still gives me the same error @DStanley

Comment: @David good catch- should be `Request["blogid"]`

Comment: @David, I.... don't?

Comment: @davidxc: Then that's probably the error.  There is no method in the current context called `Request`.  There is a *property* on the `Page` object called `Request`, of type `HttpRequest`, which itself has lots of other properties and methods.  Maybe you're looking for something in there?

Comment: @davidxc `HttpRequest` has an [_indexer_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item(v=vs.110).aspx) which uses square brackets instead of parentheses.   It will let you pull values from the query string, form variables, cookies, or server variables without having to specify which you want to search (e.g. `Request["blogid"]` instead of `Request.QueryString["blogid"]`)

Comment: @DStanley I swear there's a way I can use Request without class references? Or did I make that up?

Comment: @davidxc The `Request` property of `Page` is an `HttpRequest` - all you need to do is change `()` to `[]`.  It's just a syntax problem.

Comment: @DStanley sq brackets still gives me the same error?

Comment: Thanks guys, managed a fix:  `string blogId = HttpContext.Current.Request["blogid"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay! Managed to fix it:

```
    string blogId = HttpContext.Current.Request["blogid"];
```

Thank God for that :-)